# Showing a counter example $(A\times B)\times C=A\times (B\times C)$

Tags: relations

Showing a counter example

$(A\times B)\times C=A\times (B\times C)$

I think

$A=\{1\}$

$B=\{2\}=C$

Would work but I am not sure...

Comment: What is the operation?

Comment: Are you speaking of [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) ?

Comment: Cross products are non associative

Comment: yes the cartesian product

Comment: How hard is it to check? It's just **one** triplet on each side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $A=B=C=\{\emptyset\}$. Then 
$$ (A\times B)\times C=\{((\emptyset,\emptyset),\emptyset)\}$$
whereas
$$ A\times (B\times C)=\{(\emptyset,(\emptyset,\emptyset))\}$$
This *looks* different.
If we use the definition $(x,y):=\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$, we see that indeed 
$$\begin{align} (\emptyset,\emptyset)&=\{\{\emptyset\}\},&\text{ hence}\\
(A\times B)\times C& = \{ \{  \{\{\{\emptyset\}\}\},\{ \emptyset  ,\{\{\emptyset\}\}\}\}  \}&\text{and}\\
A\times (B\times C)&=\{  \{  \{\emptyset\},\{\{\emptyset\},\{\{\emptyset\}\} \}    \}   \}
\end{align}$$
which are truely different sets.

Comment: On the other hand: You are aware that there is a *canonical* bijecton $A\times (B\times C)\to (A\times B)\times C$?

Comment: hmm I think I get it a bit hard to the theory.

Comment: No I did not know about it

Comment: @Hagen Not sure what your point was. A bijection is a weaker condition then set equality. The 2 dimensional real space has a canonical set isomorphism to the complex plane via the coordinate ordered pairs (x,y) where x,y are real numbers,but they clearly are NOT equal as sets. Indeed, the complex plane isn't even a Cartesian product in set-theoretic sense.

Comment: @Hagen (addendum) That being said, a VERY good counterexample indeed-simple and very clear!